# Does not conform to the protocol UITableViewDataSource

Tags: uitableview, swift

I want to do a Table view in swift and I'm getting the following error

> "does not conform to the protocol UITableViewDataSource"

Can any one suggest where I'm going wrong?

```
import UIKit

class WalkthroughScreen2ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{

   let cityArray = ["Portland","San Francisco","Cupertino"]
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.createReminderLabel()



        // Create our UITableView with our view's frame
        var tableView: UITableView = UITableView(frame: self.view.frame)


        // Register our cell's class for cell reuse
        tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")

        // Set our source and add the tableview to the view
        tableView.dataSource = self
        self.view.addSubview(tableView)
   }



    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return cityArray.count
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
        // dequeue a cell for the given indexPath
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        // set the cell's text with the new string formatting
        cell.textLabel.text = "\(cityArray[indexPath.row])"

        return cell
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signature of `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is incorrect in your code, it should be:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

the difference is that `tableView` is not an optional. Also you have to implement this method:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
```

Similarly, `numberOfRowsInSection` signature is:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
```